# Old asp application works on Vista but not on Windows 7

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, oledb, jet

I have an old asp application I am trying to move from a Vista machine to a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I developed the application but am not an expert web developer. The home page is rendering properly with no errors but the data from the Access database is not populating. The variable strConnect holds the connection string. The connection string I'm using is this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Personal_Inventory\Inventory_Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False
```

The database is in the correct location in the connection string. I call the database with this code:

```
Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
                            objCommand.ActiveConnection = strConnect
                            objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ClassID, Classification_Eng FROM Classification ORDER BY 
Classification_Eng"

                            Set objRS = objCommand.Execute
                            Set objCommand = Nothing

                            While Not objRS.EOF
                                Response.Write "<OPTION VALUE = " & objRS("ClassID") & ">" & _
                                objRS("Classification_Eng") & "</OPTION>"
                                objRS.MoveNext
                            Wend

                            objRS.Close
                            Set objRS = nothing
```

I have two copies of the msjet40.dll:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-m..-components-jetcore_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_046511bf090691ab
```

and

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

The are both version 4.0.9756.0.

This application worked fine on the Vista machine. I have enabled the asp components on Windows 7--what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to go to Application pool settings in IIS manager and choose to allow 32 bit applications in the Default Application Pool.